# Spring Boot application returns "Sources must not be empty"

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
package io.springframework;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication()

public class SpringApi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new SpringApplication.run(SpringApi.class ,args);

    }

}
```

I am getting this error:

> Sources must not be empty

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: How did you get on with this, did Vijay's suggestion work?

Answer (score 0):

`@SpringBootApplication()` is wrong, should be `@SpringBootApplication`.